# Vector of strings with a counter C++

Tags: c++, vector, counter

I am inputting a file of characters and each word gets its own spot in a vector. I then need to keep track of each word and find out how many times each unique word appeared such that:

There are three trees trees trees

should output:

There 1
are 1
three 1
trees 3

I was wondering how to use a vector of strings to keep tract of each word. 
Would I do a vector of strings with each string having a vector of a single int?

Comment: Why not use a `std::map`?

Comment: `unordered_map<string, int>` is probably what you want. (`unordered_multiset`, on second look, has some weirdness; why would count be linear in number of matching items?)

Comment: It's not trivial with associative containers. It seems you still need to track the order the words appear in the input.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's not clear if that's a requirement, but if it is then it's still pretty trivial, just keep a `vector<string>` as well, and every time the new string doesn't already appear in the associative container, `push_back` into the vector.

Comment: This question needs substantial clarification. Are you simply trying to print the *frequency* of distinct words from standard input? That's fairly trivial in only a few lines of code with a properly managed associative container from strings to counters. Tracking *where* each word appears is only a little more involved. However, maintaining input order for your output is *considerably* more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Don't drive a nail with a screwdriver. A `std::vector`, isn't particularly useful for this task at its most-basic form  : simple frequency calculation. Arbitrary input from standard input would best utilize an associative container, where the key is the input string, and the value is an accumulated frequency.

**Unordered Frequency Calculation**

A unordered mapping class, [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), keying on `std::string` and mapping to a frequency counter for that string, can be used to track basic frequency. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned> m;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        ++m[word]; // increment the count for this word

    for (auto const& pr : m)
        std::cout << pr.first << ':' << pr.second << '\n';
}
```

**Lexicographical Ordered Frequency**

Note: there is no specific *order* to using the associative container `std::unordered_map` (hence the name). If you desired lexicographical ordering, you could simply use a regular [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> m;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        ++m[word];

    for (auto const& pr : m)
        std::cout << pr.first << ':' << pr.second << '\n';
}
```

**Positional Retention Frequency Calculation**

Maintaining where, within the input stream, a word appears while calculating the frequency counter is also possible, and takes only a little more code. Choose either the unordered or ordered associative container as we did before, but rather than mapping to `unsigned`, we map to [`std::vector<unsigned>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), where we accumulate a word counter as we consume input words. The overall size of each vector still retains the frequency counter but the vector itself retains the position within the input stream the associated word appears. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<unsigned int>> m;
    std::string word;
    unsigned ctr = 0;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        m[word].push_back(++ctr);

    for (auto const& pr : m)
    {
        std::cout << pr.first << ':' << pr.second.size() << " { ";
        for (auto pos : pr.second)
            std::cout << pos << ' ';
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

This will produce output of the form:

```
word : frequency { n1 n2 n3... }
```

where `word` is a distinct word, `frequency` is the overall frequency in the input stream, and `n1,n2,n3,...` are the positions (starting at 1) where the word appeared during processing.

Hopefully, one of these methods is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiset class from c++ which will keep track of how many times you added each word to the set. Also keep in mind you can read complete words from in streams in c++ and it will automatically skip any space characters.

I will read from stdin for this example (note, I did not compile this, it's just to show the idea).

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string word;
  multiset<string> ocurrences;
  while(cin >> word){
    ocurrences.insert(word);
  }
  for(string w : ocurrences){  // Iterate over all words in the set
    cout<<w<<" "<<counts.count(w)<<" ";
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to print the words in the order of first ocurrence, just keep a `vector<string>` and add each word you read if it's not already in the set, then iterate over this vector instead of the set.

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string word;
  vector<string> words;
  multiset<string> ocurrences;
  while(cin >> word){
    if(ocurrences.count(word) == 0) //Is this the first time we see this word?
      words.push_back(word);
    ocurrences.insert(word);
  }
  for(string w : words){ //Iterate over the words in the order
                         //they appeared in the input.
    cout<<w<<" "<<ocurrences.count(w)<<" ";
  }
}
```

Another thing, even though a multiset is better suited to fix this specific problem, what you are asking about in your question is called a map, a data structure which associates a key to a value (possibly of different types). [C++ already has a map implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). In this case you would need a `map<string, int>` to associate each word to the times it occurs.

Comment: I read over the `multi*set` data structures in C++, and I realized I don't really understand them. It seems like they are designed to store multiple instances of things that *compare* equal, but are not the same. `count` for `multiset` is logarithmic in total items, *plus* linear in number of items found. There's no reason why that would be the case unless it's storing all the copies of the inserted element. That being the case, `multi_*` structures are a bad fit when you are counting truly identical things.

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out, I basically chose the data structure based on it's interface, I kind of assumed it was implemented internally as a map which counted occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do this by accumulating your dictionary over a stream of words and using C++17 structured bindings:

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream words( "There are three trees trees trees" );

    auto dic = std::accumulate(
        std::istream_iterator< std::string >( words ) ,
        std::istream_iterator< std::string >( ) ,
        std::unordered_map< std::string , int >( ) ,
        []( auto && map , auto && word ) -> decltype( auto )
        {
            auto [ it , success ] = map.try_emplace(
                std::forward< decltype( word ) >( word ) , 0 );

            ++ it->second;

            return std::forward< decltype( map ) >( map );
        } );

    for ( const auto & [ key , value ] : dic )
    {
        std::cout << key << ": " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c928432ca76db09e) (with some warnings though)

```
> trees: 3
> three: 1
> There: 1
> are: 1
```